VBA Initialize Global Static Array
I am trying to create a global array that can be referenced across multiple modules. I've been searching and searching and can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Essentially, I want to store this array in it's own module called modArrays. Then I want to be able to initialize that array in a Combobox during the UserForm initialize event. I'm sure this is an extremely simple task, I just can't find out how to make it work.
modArray Module
Option Explicit

Public gTransTypeArray As Variant

Sub gTransTypeArrayPopulate()
    
    gTransTypeArray = Array( _
        "Acquisition", _
        "Disposition", _
        "Lease", _
        "Easement", _
        "Condemnation", _
        "Purchase Option", _
        "Right of First Refusal/Offer" _
        )
    
End Sub

UserForm
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cmboTransType.List = modArrays.gTransTypeArrayPopulate
End Sub


What's the specific problem you're having? cmboTransType.List = modArrays.gTransTypeArrayPopulate won't work because the initialization method doesn't return anything.  You need to first call gTransTypeArrayPopulate and then cmboTransType.List = gTransTypeArray

I've gotten a bunch of different errors. I made the switch you recommended and it worked! chalk one up for learning that I have to call the function into the module before I can initialize the array into the Combo Box

You may as well do this
Option Explicit

Function gTransTypeArray() As Variant
    
    gTransTypeArray = Array( _
        "Acquisition", _
        "Disposition", _
        "Lease", _
        "Easement", _
        "Condemnation", _
        "Purchase Option", _
        "Right of First Refusal/Offer" _
        )
End Sub

then
cmboTransType.List = modArrays.gTransTypeArray

There's not much to be gained here by having the Global and needing to initialize it.

So clearly I'm still learning. I've been watching Youtube Videos and such and they've all referenced that I need to initialize the UserForm so that all the Combo Boxes and List Boxes populate when the User Form loads. Is this not correct? Am I misunderstanding what does and does not need to be initialized and when?

initialize it - here the "it" I was referring to the Global array variable, not your userform.  If you have a Global variable which takes some resources to populate (eg you need to make a database call) then it makes sense to use a separate method to perform that initialization.  However in this case it's cleaner just to use a function to directly return the array.

Another approach based on this idea could be to define a class.
Attention: You have to import the following code from a text file as you cannot set the attribute VB_PredeclaredId  within VBE
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
   MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "c"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private mTransTypeArray As Variant

Private Sub TransTypeArrayPopulate()
    
    mTransTypeArray = Array( _
        "Acquisition", _
        "Disposition", _
        "Lease", _
        "Easement", _
        "Condemnation", _
        "Purchase Option", _
        "Right of First Refusal/Offer" _
        )
    
End Sub

Property Get TransTypeArray() As Variant
    TransTypeArray = mTransTypeArray
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    TransTypeArrayPopulate
End Sub

Then you could just use
cmboTransType.List= c.TransTypeArray


Ultimately the goal is to get to using a class. I'm just not there yet in terms of learning. The long term goal is to create a class for this form that I'm creating. The form will end up being sent out to field personnel fill out and will prepopulate several list boxes and combo boxes. This is probably a good place for me to start that education from but unfortunately right now I don't understand about half of your solution.

Thanks to Tim Williams!
I didn't realize I needed to call the array function into the initialize function before I could set the combo box equal to the array. Here's the code that now works.
Option Explicit
  Public gTransTypeArray As Variant
  Sub gTransTypeArrayPopulate()  
     gTransTypeArray = Array( _
      "Acquisition", _
      "Disposition", _
      "Lease", _
      "Easement", _
      "Condemnation", _
      "Purchase Option", _
      "Right of First Refusal/Offer" _
      )
 End Sub

Initialized User Form
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Call gTransTypeArrayPopulate
  cmboTransType.List = modArrays.gTransTypeArray
End Sub

